# Add node ID to template variables

Tags: theming

is there any way to add node ID (if it exists) to template variables using

```
my_theme_preprocess_page(&vars) function?
```

It looks like theme theme isn't using `my_theme_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook)` so I assume that node object isnt available in vars for `my_theme_preprocess_page(&vars)`.

It's not my website so I don't really know the structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access `nid` inside preprocess_page you should try something like this

`arg(0)` will return `'node'` and `arg(1)` will return `node nid`.

Provided you must be inside a node.

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  if ($nid) {
   $node = node_load($nid);
   // creating the node variable
   $vars['node'] = node_load(arg(1), NULL, TRUE); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What is arg() function ?

Comment: arg() function returns the arguments value from URL... refer https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7